HAProxy stats page is not displaying backend stats
I have an assignment where i have to create an automatically scaling web application. The web application is provide and it is my task to write the scaling controller and configure the load balancer and load tester.
For load balancing i have chosen HAProxy and load tester Locust.
To the problem now.
As you can see from the pic the backend is 0 all around even though the front end is displaying stats normally.

My haproxy.cfg is file code is the following which is a seprate file from the one that haproxy starts by default, in order to change the path from which haproxy starts i did the following
sudo systemctl edit haproxy

and this is what that file looks like now, note i have the changed the lines not in the comments
## Editing /etc/systemd/system/haproxy.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /home/george/Desktop/cc1/CC1/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid

### Lines below this comment will be discarded

### /lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service
# [Unit]
# Description=HAProxy Load Balancer
# Documentation=man:haproxy(1)
# Documentation=file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
# After=network-online.target rsyslog.service
# Wants=network-online.target
# [Service]
# EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/haproxy
# EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/haproxy
# Environment="CONFIG=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" "PIDFILE=/run/haproxy.pid" "EXTRAOPTS=-S /run/haproxy-master.sock"
# ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS
# ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -p $PIDFILE $EXTRAOPTS
# ExecReload=/usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -c -q $EXTRAOPTS
# ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
# KillMode=mixed
# Restart=always
# SuccessExitStatus=143
# Type=notify
# 
# # The following lines leverage SystemD's sandboxing options to provide
# # defense in depth protection at the expense of restricting some flexibility
# # in your setup (e.g. placement of your configuration files) or possibly
# # reduced performance. See systemd.service(5) and systemd.exec(5) for further
# # information.
# 
# # NoNewPrivileges=true
# # ProtectHome=true
# # If you want to use 'ProtectSystem=strict' you should whitelist the PIDFILE,
# # any state files and any other files written using 'ReadWritePaths' or
# # 'RuntimeDirectory'.
# # ProtectSystem=true
# # ProtectKernelTunables=true
# # ProtectKernelModules=true
# # ProtectControlGroups=true
# # If your SystemD version supports them, you can add: @reboot, @swap, @sync
# # SystemCallFilter=~@cpu-emulation @keyring @module @obsolete @raw-io
# 
# [Install]
# WantedBy=multi-user.target

this the haproxy.cfg file that i am working with
defaults
  mode http
  timeout client 10s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 10s 
  timeout http-request 10s
  stats enable


frontend stats
    bind *:8404
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats refresh 10s
    stats admin if LOCALHOST

frontend myfrontend
  bind 127.0.0.1:80
  mode http
  stats enable
  default_backend myservers

backend myservers
  mode http
  option http-server-close
  stats enable
  server server1 127.0.0.1:5000 check


I want to note also that the web app is running inside a podman container
